# Reuse scope-keys in multiple API-version in WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We use WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0 for our API Management. I've previously setup an API which is restricted via scopes-to-role-mapping. Now we have to handle multiple versions of this API (not all clients can migrate to the new versions at once), but it seems I can't reuse the same scopes (scope-keys and scope names) I've restricted a previous version with?

This seems strange? Does that mean I need to create unique scopes-to-role-mappings for each version of the API? That would mean that subscribers using the /default api would have to update their scope-names when requesting an access-token depending on which version of the API they're using?

What strategy should be used here? We usually create scopes with scope-key `<API-Name>-<Restriction-Key>`. Should I now then use `<API-Name>-<Version>-<Restriction-Key>`, and when users migrate, they need to update their scopes when requesting an access-token to the correct version?

I really hope it's possible for our users to simply keep using the same scopes when switching to a new version of our API somehow, or are they uniquely tied to a specific version of an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to this.

Firstly, if creating a new version of an API by using the "create a new version" in the publisher, the scopes can be reused; but as soon as you try importing a new swagger-specification the scopes are removed and can't be reused under the "manage-phase".

I found out that the scopes are actually specified in the swagger-document stored in the repository under `/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/<provider-name>/<api-name>/<api-version>/swagger.json`. The swagger-document has a property called "x-wso2-security" which includes the scopes (which is read by the publisher during the "manage-phase"). It's possible to add scopes to the swagger-document (for e.g. copying the x-wso2-security property from a previous API-version), save the resource and open up the publisher, the scopes will then show up to be used under the "manage-phase".

I assume this is something the WSO2-development-team has missed when creating the publisher, but happily, it's possible to get around it by doing some manual work as described above.